# Tensorflow keeps all files. How to prevent that?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Since updating to tensoflow version 1.0 which introduced the new Saver V2, tf does not delete old files any more with the 'max_to_keep' argument. This is a problem on my system since my models are pretty big but my free space is limited.

Using the dummy program below I end up with following files for every number from 1 to 10 while I only expect the last 3 (8,9,10) to actually be there.

- testfile-1.data-00000-of-00001
- testfile-1.index
- testfile-1.meta

program:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(name='a', initial_value=0)
addops = a+1

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=3)
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(10):
    sess.run(addops)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, 'testfile', global_step=i+1)

sess.close()
```

Is this just me or this a known bug?
What are possible problems which could lead to this misbehavior?
Is there any log or smth similar I could get more information from?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on my system. I am running TF 1.0.1 on a Windows 10 PC with a GTX 960M (not sure if that's relevant).

Comment: Thanks for trying @Engineero. I am getting the feeling that this is about my specific system/installation since I cannot find any similar problems from other people. I have TF 1.0.0 running on a Ubuntu 14.04 with a Tesla K80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this. It seems to be a bug.

However the problem is gone once I save into a different location (different from the executed .py file path)

```
    save_path = saver.save(sess, 'data/testfile', global_step=i+1)
```

Comment: this actually works for me too, thx a lot. It is a weird bug though.